# AppArmor is blocking vital functionality fof half of my installed snaps; how do I fix this issue?

Tags: kubuntu, snap, 20.04, apparmor, kdenlive

I'm running a fresh install of Kubuntu 20.04. In 19.10, I rather enjoyed using snap packages. They're complete and functional.
But, I'm running into all sorts of issues. My dmesg output is crammed with AppArmor blockages.

I installed apparmor-utils and snappy-debug and I've tried setting all profiles to complain only, yet it's still blocking a bunch of my installs. Especially Kdenlive. In fact, I can't seem to find a security profile for kdenlive anywhere.

I just re-isntalled kdenlive with the --devmode switch, so I guess we'll see how that goes. It really becomes a problem once I try to render something.

But now I'm at the point where, even if it works, I've just defeated half of the reason for using snaps in the first place. Or at least, that's what I've come to understand after the past couple of hours, having read through a fair portion of documentation.

How is this such an issue? I'm surprised at how many people are having issued with apparmor just completely out of nowhere. Kdenlive seems to be up there in the results for whatever reason.

I had no idea it even exited until I installed the new LTS 20.04

What am I missing here? Is there a simple solution to all of this?

Thanks.